# Python tkinter .pack/.pack_forget memory issue

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I've been teaching myself Python for a few months now and have proceed into learning some GUI techniques.

I wrote this simple script based off a pack_remove example I found within a book.  My script simply displays local and UTC time every second.  Granted the only difference is the hour,  I would still like to redisplay every second.

The script works, yet my RAM is consistently increasing with every time display.  I start out with around 4mb then after 2 hours or so the script uses 25mb.  This makes some sense to me,  but I was curious if there was a way display new times every second, but reduce the memory usage of such a simple clock display.

Or am I using an inefficient technique to re-display data in a GUI at a high frequency?

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
import time

class TimeDisplay(Frame):
    def __init__(self,msecs = 1000):
        Frame.__init__(self)
        self.msecs = msecs
        self.pack()
        utc_time = Label(self, text='')
        utc_time.pack()
        cst_time = Label(self, text='')
        cst_time.pack()
        self.utc_time = utc_time
        self.cst_time = cst_time
        self.repeater()

    def repeater(self):
        self.utc_time.pack_forget()
        self.cst_time.pack_forget()
        self.utc_time = Label(self, text= 'UTC: ' + time.strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S',time.gmtime()))
        self.utc_time.pack()
        self.utc_time.config(bg='navy',fg='white')
        self.cst_time = Label(self, text= 'CST: ' + time.strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S',time.localtime()))
        self.cst_time.pack()
        self.cst_time.config(bg='navy',fg='white')
        self.after(self.msecs, self.repeater)        


if __name__ == '__main__': TimeDisplay(msecs=1000).mainloop()
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pack_forget` doesn't destroy anything, it just makes it non-visible. This is a GUI version of a memory leak -- you keep creating objects without ever destroying them.

So, the first lesson to learn is that you should destroy a widget when you are done with it.

The more important lesson to learn is that you don't have to keep destroying and recreating the same widget over and over. You can change the text that is displayed with the `configure` method. For example:

```
self.utc_time.configure(text="...")
```

This will make your program not use any extra memory, and even use (imperceptibly) less CPU.

Answer (score 1):

To actually free widget's memory you should also call it's .destroy() method. This prevents memory leaking in your case.

However a more efficient way to implement the stuff is to associate string variable with Label widget like this:

```
v = StringVar()
Label(master, textvariable=v).pack()
v.set("New Text!")
```

see http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/label.htm for reference

Comment: strictly speaking, you don't need to use a `textvariable`. That's extra overhead when all you really need to do is reconfigure the text attribute.